# Why am I getting this error when installing daphne?

Tags: python, django, pip, daphne

First time attempting to run

```
py -m pip install daphne
```

from my django project directory:

> WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system can
> not find the file specified: 'C:\Python39\Scripts\automat-visualize.exe' -> '
> C:\Python39\Scripts\automat-visualize.exe.deleteme'

Second attempt:

> WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system can
> not find the file specified: 'C:\Python39\Scripts\cftp.exe' -> 'C:\Python39
> \Scripts\cftp.exe.deleteme'

Where am I supposed to get these files from?

Also everytime I run the command, there are new files that I apparently don't have (e.g. swamp.exe, daphne.exe)

Comment: Getting the same thing when trying to install `scrapy`

Answer (score 3):

Had to run PowerShell as admin then `pip install scrapy` (in my case) to get past the error your reported.

Answer (score -1):

just start cmd as Administrator, this will solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).